# How to handle typing of member variable that is initialized during __post_init__() of dataclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, python-dataclasses

The variable below is initialized as none, but during `__post_init__` it is replaced with an instance of  outlook client.

```
@dataclass
class Config:
    """Outlook configuration"""

    mailbox: str
    inbox: str
    mailbox_obj: Union["Mailbox", None] = None
```

However, static type analysis correctly informs that mailbox_obj has no members (...is not a known member of "None"). I don't want to guard everything with `if mailbox_obj` just to satisfy the type analysis. Is there another way using a dataclass field or something?

The problem would go away if I just used a regular class since I can initialize the problem variable in **init** where the type will be inferred to it's set value, but then I have to write that extra boilerplate.

Writing this question has reminded me of the below, which is probably what I'm looking for:

```
    mailbox_obj: "Mailbox" = field(init=False)
```

Is that the right way?

Comment: Could you post a [mre]? This code passes mypy even with `--strict` once you fill in some blanks (`from dataclasses import dataclass; from typing import Union; class Mailbox: pass`).

Comment: BTW, `Union["Mailbox", None]` can be simplified to `Optional["Mailbox"]`.

Comment: You can't, but why are you doing things this way?  Just use `field(init=False)`

Comment: I feel that `Optional["Mailbox"]` would be just as incorrect as the Union typing in that case, since the variable is not optional to be set at all. It's just initially `None`, not optionally `None` etc. But good reminder that Optional represents `Object | None` etc. In 3.1X you can use the Union shorthand too. This codebase is 3.97 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want to specify that it is not an init field, so you just want something like this:

```
import dataclasses

class Mailbox:
    pass

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Config:
    """Outlook configuration"""

    mailbox: str
    inbox: str
    mailbox_obj: "Mailbox" = dataclasses.field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        # do some stuff...
        self.mailbox_obj = Mailbox()
```

I saved the above code in a file called `test_typing.py` and here is mypy:

```
(py310) Juans-MBP:test juan$ mypy test_typing.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Awesome, this is the answer. The implicit import of the entire dataclasses module makes it clear (perhaps to future me/others) where `field` and `dataclass` come from as a bonus.